# Can I use template parameter as variable?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I want to allocate memory according to the template parameter like this:

```cpp
enum typeFlag {
kFloat32 = 0,
kFloat64 = 1,
kFloat16 = 2,
kUint8 = 3,
kInt32 = 4,
kInt8  = 5,
kInt64 = 6,
kBool = 7,
kInt16 = 8
};

template<typename dtype, typename ctx>
inline TBlob<dtype,ctx>::TBlob(const size_t &size): shape_{size} {
    switch(dtype){
        case kFloat32:
            dptr_ = new float[size];
            break;
        case kFloat64:
            dptr_ = new double[size];
            break;
...
```

and the compiler throw an error like:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     switch(dtype){
                 ^
```

Can I achieve my goal while keeping the same meaning of `dtype`?

Comment: Yes, but as currently written, your template parameter is a type name, not a value.  Try `template<typeFlag dtype, typename ctx>`

Comment: You don't want to use it as a variable. You want to use a value template parameter instead of a type template parameter. For a variable-like parameter, you could use a reference.

Comment: @IllidanS4 supports Monica Yes! Your description is more accurate, and I learn from your advice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to map a non-template (enumerator) parameter to a type:

```
#include <cstddef>

// Platform-independent type descriptions.
enum class TypeFlag {
kFloat32 = 0,
kFloat64 = 1
    // ...
};

// Platform-specific TypeFlag to type mapping.
template<TypeFlag FLAG>
struct MappedType;

// Specialize type mapping for the platform-independent
// type representations (TypeFlag) that can be represented
// on this particular platform.
template<>
struct MappedType<TypeFlag::kFloat32> { using type = float; };

template<>
struct MappedType<TypeFlag::kFloat64> { using type = double; };

// ...

template<TypeFlag FLAG>
using MappedType_t = typename MappedType<FLAG>::type;

template<TypeFlag FLAG, std::size_t SIZE>
struct TBlob {
    using BlobType = MappedType_t<FLAG>;

    TBlob() {
        dptr_ = new BlobType[SIZE];
    }

    // ...

private:
    BlobType* dptr_;
};
```

Note that `double` isn't necessarily a 64 bit float on all target architectures, so this approach is not necessarily portable, and would arguably go into a platform-specific type mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! it helped me to learn more knowledge beyond this question.

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly can. I am guessing your current definition is like this

```
template<typename dType> ... everything else
```

You should change that to non-type parameter and it will work as expected. Either

```
template<int dType> ... rest of definition
```

or

```
template<typeFlag dType> ... rest of definition
```

should work depending upon your language version.

You can read about it further [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter).

Comment: Thank you! It really helps!